# Must I UN-parent the child object to keyframe it?

Tags: keyframes, parent

I've tried keyframing child objects, and always get wonky results. Keyframes earlier on the timeline become wildly different and unusable. It seems necessary to UN-parent the child in order to make useful keyframes. Is there a way to properly keyframe child objects without un-parenting them first?

Comment: Can you give us an example blend file? It is normally possible to still keyframe it while it is a child, and it will perform both its keyframe movements and its parent movements - hence why most child objects only ever have rotation/scale keyframes.

Comment: It's rendering now, so I'll upload a blend in a few hours.

Comment: The response is an absolutely no, you must not unparent for keyframing. Actually, most bones are children in rigs. Something in your workflow may be mistaken. Maybe are you adding keyframes in visual Loc/Rot/Scale?

Comment: Hmmm ... I just created a simple test scene, and keyframing a child object does seem to work as expected. This makes me wonder if something else in my more complex scenes is making this not work as it should. ... Jury still out.  :+)

Comment: @ Antonio Buch - I agree it's bad to need to unparent before keyframing, which could destroy other things in a scene. I think you must be correct about my workflow, because this works in simple scenes, but not in my more complex scenes. -- Another mystery to be solved ...